# How to use a filter to handle exception that are throws in the servlet

Tags: java, servlets, filter, servlet-filters

My purpose  is create a Filter to handle the exception that are throwed in the servlet.

Suppose I have this filter:

```
public class FiltroAccess implements Filter{

    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        //handle exception

    }

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

and in my `servlet` I throws the `Exception`

How can I must do to handle in my filter the Exeception ?

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just enclose the filter chain call in a try/catch block:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        arg2.doFilter(arg0, arg1);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle exception here
    }
}
```

The only problem is that is the ServletResponse has already be committed (sent to the client) you will not be able to change the headers.

Comment: it doesn't work, because the filter doesn't enter in the catch block. I need to call filter when an Exception is  throw but I don't know  how I can do?

Comment: *call the filter when a Exception is thrown* is nonsence. The filter must be declared to filter the servlet. Once it is, it will be called in the filter chain before the servlet and if the servlet throws, the exception will be caught in the catch block of the filter.